# jquery, trying to bind event to tr but it's also applied to child elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a row click event on a table populated by json data. The row click itselves works but it's also applied to child elements such as checkboxes and buttons which are in the row cells.

```
$('#results tbody  tr').live("click",function(){
    
});
```

That's the way i'm selecting the table row, maybe i'm missing something very obvious here? Probably!

Thanks for your time!
regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you don't handle the clicks coming from the sub-elements (or cancel their propagation) they will bubble up to the `tr`

Either do something to `return false;` on sub-element clicks to stop the event propagation,  or view the event coming in to your function above, an see what triggered it,  if it was a sub-element, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent input and checkbox click events from bubbling up.

```
$('#results tbody  tr:input', '#results tbody  tr:checkbox').live("click",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```